# What does percentage mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering what "percentage" means in this sentence:

> Our competitor orders a high percentage of its equipment from foreign companies.

Does it mean "quality" here? Could someone please help me to explain this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Answer (score 6):

It refers to the amount of the equipments not the quality .

It means "Our competitor orders a lot of its equipment from foreign companies."

Answer (score 6):

In the phrase

> "Our competitor orders a high **percentage** of its equipment from
>   foreign companies."

the word *percentage* means *quantity* relative to the overall amount of equipment usually ordered by the competitor over some period of time.

The competitor might order 100 pieces of equipment per year, of which 60%, or 60 pieces, would come from foreign companies. That's *a high percentage*, despite the fact that 100 pieces might be a small amount in that particular line of business. Other companies might be ordering 1000 pieces of equipment per year, but still 60 out of 100 is *a high percentage* for our particular competitor.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is "proportion." "Our competitor orders a high **proportion** of its equipment from foreign companies"